# macOS Sierra — Changing the pre-boot login screen profile picture

Tags: mac, macos

Is there a way to replace the (ugly) profile picture on the pre-boot login screen:

[image: profile picture on the pre-boot login screen]

…with my iCould profile picture on macOS Sierra (10.12.3)?

Comment: I find that this picture only shows up on my main user account right after startup. Oddly, my other user accounts all show the images they're supposed to show right after a restart, but that main one shows the weird shadowy image above.